# Rolling sum over multiple columns in r

Tags: r, for-loop, rolling-computation

I am working on R with a dataset that looks like this:

[Screen shot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz3AH.jpg)

```
test=data.frame("1991" = c(1,5,3), "1992" = c(4,3,3), "1993" = c(10,5,3), "1994" = c(1,1,1), "1995" = c(2,2,6))
test=plyr::rename(test, c("X1991"="1991", "X1992"="1992", "X1993"="1993", "X1994"="1994", "X1995"="1995"))
```

What I want to do is that I want to create variables called Pre1991, Pre1992, Pre1993, ... and these variables would store the cumulated values up to that year, e.g.

```
Pre1991 = test$1991
Pre1992 = test$1991 + test$1992
Pre1993 = test$1991 + test$1992 + test$1993
```

so on.

My real dataset has variables from year 1900-2017 so I can't do this manually. I want to write a for loop but it didnt work.

```
for (i in 1900:2017){
  x = paste0("Pre",i)
  df[[x]] = rowSums(df[,(colnames(df)<=i)]) 
}
```

Can someone please help to review my code/ suggest other ways to do it? Thanks!

Edit 1:

Thanks so much! And I'm wondering if there's a way that I can use cumsum function in a reverse direction? For example, if I am interested in what happened after that particular year:

```
Post1991 = test$1992 + test$1993 + test$1994 + test$1995 + ...
Post1992 = test$1993 + test$1994 + test$1995 + ...
Post1993 = test$1994 + test$1995 + ...
```

Comment: Thanks everyone!!!!

Comment: If any of the answers helped you it would be fitting to accept an answer or upvote them.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little inefficient in that it is converting from a `data.frame` to a `matrix` and back, but ...

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(as.matrix(test), 1, cumsum)))
#   1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
# 1    1    5   15   16   18
# 2    5    8   13   14   16
# 3    3    6    9   10   16
```

If your data has other columns that are not year-based, such as

```
test$quux <- LETTERS[3:5]
test
#   1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 quux
# 1    1    4   10    1    2    C
# 2    5    3    5    1    2    D
# 3    3    3    3    1    6    E
```

then subset on both sides:

```
test[1:5] <- as.data.frame(t(apply(as.matrix(test[1:5]), 1, cumsum)))
test
#   1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 quux
# 1    1    5   15   16   18    C
# 2    5    8   13   14   16    D
# 3    3    6    9   10   16    E
```

---

**EDIT**

In reverse, just use repeated `rev`:

```
as.data.frame(t(apply(as.matrix(test), 1, function(a) rev(cumsum(rev(a)))-a)))
#   1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
# 1   17   13    3    2    0
# 2   11    8    3    2    0
# 3   13   10    7    6    0
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way I can do cumsum in a reverse direction? Please refer to my updated question above. Thanks!

Comment: OP's reverse definition is excluding the current year.

Comment: Ok ... odd, but fixed. (This is really not the best format for this data ...)

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` we can gather and calculate before then spreading again. For this to work data will need to be arranged.

```
library(tidyverse)
test <- data.frame("1991" = c(1, 5, 3),
                   "1992" = c(4, 3, 3),
                   "1993" = c(10, 5, 3),
                   "1994" = c(1, 1, 1),
                   "1995" = c(2, 2, 6))
test <- plyr::rename(test, c("X1991" = "1991",
                             "X1992" = "1992",
                             "X1993" = "1993",
                             "X1994" = "1994",
                             "X1995" = "1995"))
```

---

### Forwards

```
test %>%
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>% # adding an ID to identify groups
  gather(year, value, -id) %>% # wide to long format
  arrange(id, year) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = cumsum(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(year, value) %>%  # long to wide format
  select(-id) %>%
  setNames(paste0("pre", names(.))) # add prefix to columns

##  A tibble: 3 x 5
#   pre1991 pre1992 pre1993 pre1994 pre1995
#     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1      1.      5.     15.     16.     18.
# 2      5.      8.     13.     14.     16.
# 3      3.      6.      9.     10.     16.
```

---

### Reverse direction

As your definition specifies its not strictly the reverse order, its the reverse order excluding itself which would be the cumulative lagged sum.

```
test %>%
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  gather(year, value, -id) %>%
  arrange(id, desc(year)) %>% # using desc() to reverse sorting
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value = cumsum(lag(value, default = 0))) %>% # lag cumsum
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(year, value) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  setNames(paste0("post", names(.)))


## A tibble: 3 x 5
#   post1991 post1992 post1993 post1994 post1995
#      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1      17.      13.       3.       2.       0.
# 2      11.       8.       3.       2.       0.
# 3      13.      10.       7.       6.       0.
```

---

Comment: Thanks very much! Is there a way I can do cumsum in a reverse direction? Please refer to my updated question above. Thanks!

Comment: @DataScienceBeginner check my revised answer

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowCumsums` from `matrixStats`

```
library(matrixStats)
test[] <- rowCumsums(as.matrix(test))
test
#  1991 1992 1993 1994 1995
#1    1    5   15   16   18
#2    5    8   13   14   16
#3    3    6    9   10   16
```